# energy of a convolution

Tags: fourier-analysis, convolution, signal-processing

I have to find the energy of $y(t)$
$$h(t)=ho\;sinc^3(t/T)\\
x(t)=V_0+V_1\;sin(3\pi\; t/T)\\
y(t)=x*h\;(t)
$$
Where "$*$" is the convolution and $sinc(t)=\frac {sin(\pi t)}{\pi t}$

I think that the best way is to use the Fourier transform to find $Y(f)$ and then use the Parseval theorem, but I can't find the $sinc^3$ Fourier transform.
My idea is:
$$sinc^3(t/T) = sinc^2(t/T)\; sinc(t/T)$$
then
$$\mathscr{F}[sinc^3(t/T)]=\{ T\; triangle(f\;T)\}*\{ T\; rect(f\;T)\} $$

But I can't solve this convolution.
Can someone solve the entire problem?

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, you want the convolution, as you say, of "triangle" with "rectangle".

In other words, you have the functions $$f(x) = \begin{cases}1,&|x|\le 1\\0,&|x|>0\end{cases}$$
and
$$g(x) = \begin{cases}1-x/2,&x\in[0,2]\\1+x/2,&x\in[-2,0]\\0,&|x|>2.\end{cases}$$

Now you need to find their convulution: first of all, it will be zero outside the interval $[-3,3]$, and inside it you can easily find the result - you have nothing but polynomials here. Hint: the piecewise result should be  polynomial of the second degree.

Comment: Yes, I know this hint, but I can't write the integral in the piece when rect touch the two sides of the triangle